# groupBy data using JavaPairdRdd

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've below code snippet

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Row>> rdd = ss.read().option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",")
        .csv("D:\\Notes\\data\\datasetOne.txt").toJavaRDD().groupBy(row -> row.getString(row.fieldIndex("key")));
```

Its grouping the data, but am not able to understand how the grouping section is working in code  `groupBy(row -> row.getString(row.fieldIndex("key")))` ?

1. Can anyone share any small data example to see how this grouping part is working ?
2. `JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Row>> rdd` Does this mean that all entries associated with the unique keys are stored in `List` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("csv test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
spark.read().csv("/tmp/test.csv").toJavaRDD().groupBy(row -> row.getString(row.fieldIndex("_c0"))).foreach(row -> {
    System.out.printf("=== %s ===%n", row._1);
    row._2.forEach(value -> System.out.printf("  %s%n", value));
});
```

with the `/tmp/test.csv` file

```
foo,bar1
bar,foo2
foo,bar2
bar,foo1
```

you get

```
=== foo ===
  [foo,bar1]
  [foo,bar2]
=== bar ===
  [bar,foo2]
  [bar,foo1]
```

your data is grouped by the specified field and the *full row* is available to iterate (note: this is not a list, is an iterator processed in an streaming way).